# Vue axios delete request not working. How do I fix it?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

Im having issues with delete request, my post, get are working fine.
What am I doing wrong?

```
 removeUser(id) {
      axios.delete('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users' + id)
      .then(function(response) {
        const user = response.data;
        this.users.splice(id, user);
      });
```

Comment: try `typicode.com/users/' + id`

Comment: I also tried that, doesn't work

Comment: "delete" method doesn't return data. Just an empty object.

Comment: How do I make it return data? I have this in my data `return {users: [],}`

Answer (score 0):

if `response.status === 204`, then delete is succeed.

for the client, here is an axios example, notice there is a `'` after `users`

```
destroy() {
    return request.delete('/api/users/' + id)
}
```

for the server, here is an Laravel example:

```
if( $article->delete() ) {
    return response()->json(null, 204);
} else {
    abort(409);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see only 1 problem on the code you provided.

You're trying to modify the Vue instance $data  `users` object by executing `this.users.splice(id, user);`. But you're inside the callback function and `this` no longer represents the Vue instance.
To fix this & make the `users` object actually modify after the response comes you'll need to do it like this :

```
 removeUser(id) {
  let that = this;
  axios.delete('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users' + id)
  .then(function(response) {
    const user = response.data;
    that.users.splice(id, user);
  });
```

Now , I don't have any code from the back-end so I'll just make some assumptions :

- The route might not be well defined > if you're using NodeJS then you should check your routes , it should look like this :

  ```
  router.route('/users:id').delete(async function(req,res,next){ /* ... */ });
  ```
- You might have a route problem because `/` is missing before the user value

1 hint : Again , if you're using NodeJS , you could use this inside your `.delete` route :

```
  res.status(200).json({ errorCode : null , errorMessage : null , users : [] });
```

To see if you're receiving it on front-end.

Answer (score -1):

I think you do need to append the trailing '/' to the URL, that way the URL is properly formed, such as "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/123" (rather than "users123" at the end).

Aside from that, the first parameter to [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is the position where item removal should begin. The second (optional) parameter, `deleteCount`, is the number of items to remove. Beyond `deleteCount`, you can pass a collection of objects which are to be inserted after the `start` position and after items have been removed.

You just need to find the object in your `this.users` array and remove it. If you want to use `Array.prototype.splice` for that, then you can use [Array.prototype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find the index of the user in the array then remove it:

```js
// Find the index of the item to remove
const indexOfUserToRemove = this.users.findIndex(u => u.id === id);

// Call splice to remove the item
this.users.splice(indexOfUserToRemove, 1);
```